# Барьеры в строках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим у нас есть строка. "КеКЕкК"
Как посчитать в ней количество барьеров между большими и маленькими буквами?
Например "КеКЕкК" барьеров 4. Барьеры для 1 и последнего символа считаются только с одной стороны относительно всего текста строки.

"SaSS" тут 2

"S" тут 0

Пытался сделать с помощью регулярки но не получилось, как можно это сделать чтобы возвращалось число барьеров?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Расскажите подробнее про "барьеры".

Comment: Как бы объяснить. Вот у нас есть в строке верхний регистр и нижний, нужно найти количество разделений между ними.
То есть вот в строке "Sa" один барьер между S и маленькой буквой 'a'. в свою очередь в строке "SaSS" барьера 2, один перед S потом второй перед "a". В строке "S" барьеров нет так как она состоит из одного символа который не соединен с символами в нижнем регистре. Таким образом строки "SSSS" и "aaaaa" тоже вернут 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, регулярками, мне кажется, вполне реальным

```
([a-z](?=[A-Z]))|([A-Z](?=[a-z]))
```

ищем прописную после строчной или наоборот

и считаем количество групп - 4

---

```js
const regex = /([a-z](?=[A-Z]))|([A-Z](?=[a-z]))/gm;
const str = `KeKEkK`;

console.log(str.match(regex).length)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/d7Djgf/1)

Comment: а как эти группы посчитать?

Comment: Js ругается Unexpected token '?'

Answer (score 1):

Лично я считаю, что использование регулярных выражений - чит.

Вместо них, с моей точки зрения, если бы пришлось принимать задание, было бы интересно, как человек сможет его решить, используя базовые конструкции языка.

Я бы предложил сделать так:

- запомнить регистр первой буквы

далее в цикле по оставшейся строке:

- если регистр сменился, то увеличиваем счетчик барьера
- запоминаем регистр текущей буквы

Можно учесть появление пробельных символов (регистр сбрасывать, счетчик не увеличиваем).

В конце выводим счетчик барьеров.